# Only the last stored data is shown in a stack view

Tags: ios, xcode, uistackview, swift5

I am making an API call which return a set of key-value pair which I want to display on the screen. I am using an xib file and adding the key-value pair to it. Only the last key value pair is shown on the display. This is done using MVVM architecture.

```
@IBOutlet var currentBenefitsStackView: UIStackView!

func populateMemberBenefits(_ data: ResponseData) {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "StackView", bundle: Bundle.SampleAccount)
        if let memberBenefitsView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? StackView {
             guard let memberBenefitsPerks = data.benifts else {return} //data.benifts contains the key value pairs
            for benefits in memberBenefitsPerks {
                memberBenefitsView.labelText?.text = benefits.value
                let imageURL = URL(string: "\(SampleURL)")
                let image = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL!)
                memberBenefitsView.imageView.image = UIImage(data: image!)
                currentBenefitsStackView.addArrangedSubview(memberBenefitsView)
            }
```

Only the last memberBenefitsView image is shown in the currentBenefitsStackView. Can anyone point to me where I am making a mistake or if any further information is required.

Comment: You need to allocate a new `memberBenefitsView` in your `for` loop, otherwise you are just continually updating the same one.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks! But that's what I am trying to do. Update the memberBenefitsView continually and keep adding it to the currentBenefitsStackView. The currentBenefitsStackView will contain all the memberBenefitsView as it is added with addArrangedSubView. Or is my understanding of your comment incorrect?

Comment: It is. You only allocate a single benefits view and keep updating it. You need to allocate one from the nib inside the for loop. Also, why aren't you simply using a table view for this?

Comment: @Paulw11 Got it. Thanks! I am not sure if how to accept an answer given in comments. I will accept it if you post the same in the answer section. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only allocating a single `memberBenefitsView` and you keep updating that.  It will be left with the final values assigned.

You need to allocate a view in each iteration of your `for` loop:

```
func populateMemberBenefits(_ data: ResponseData) {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "StackView", bundle: Bundle.SampleAccount)
    guard let memberBenefitsPerks = data.benifts else {return} //data.benifts contains the key value pairs
    for benefits in memberBenefitsPerks {
        if let memberBenefitsView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? StackView {
            memberBenefitsView.labelText?.text = benefits.value
            let imageURL = URL(string: "\(SampleURL)")
            let image = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL!)
            memberBenefitsView.imageView.image = UIImage(data: image!)
            currentBenefitsStackView.addArrangedSubview(memberBenefitsView)
        }
    }
}
```